# How to crosstab columns from dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I often need cross tables for pre-analysis of my data. I can produce a basic cross table with `pd.crosstab(df['column'], df['column'])` but fail to add a crition (logical expression), to filter this cross table only to a subset of my dataframe.

I've tried `pd.crosstab(df['health'], df['money']) if df['year']==1988` and several postions for the if. I hope it's easy to solve, but I'm relatively new to Python and Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1988', '1988', '1988', '1989', '1989', '1989', '1989'],
                   'health': ['2', '2', '3', '1', '3', '5', '2', '1'],
                   'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8']}).astype(int)

# cross table for 1988 and 1999
pd.crosstab(df['health'], df['money'])
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab([df['year'], df['health']], df['money']).loc[1988]` ..?

Comment: That's also great! How can I extend it to multiple conditions? I have several years and sometimes I need to filter/subset for two. Somethin like `loc[1988 || 2002]`. Regards

Comment: I found the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html never mind, e.g. `loc[1988:2002]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) before `crosstab`:

```
df1 = df[df['year']==1988]
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['health'], df1['money'])
```

EDIT: You can filter each column separately:

```
mask = df['year']==1988
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.loc[mask, 'health'], df.loc[mask, 'money'])
```

Comment: I've seen this kind of filtering/subsetting before cross-tab analysis. This creates new df right? Since my dataframe is really big, I've tried to circumvent this option. Is there a way of addition logical options to the crosstab function? Regards